# Bootstrap-datepicker eternicode get date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm completely new to js/jquery. For my django app i need to get selected date and then process it with ajax script.

I'm using bootstrap-datepicker from eternicode. Here is my html:

> ```
> <form style="color: white;" class="form-date" role="form" action="" method="get">
>    <div class="form-group" id="datepicker">
>        <div></div>
>        <input type="hidden" name="dt_due" id="dt_due">
>    </div>
>    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-home">Go to summary</button>
> </form>
> ```

And here is my js for testing:

```
$('#datepicker div').datepicker({
    language:"fr",
    startDate: "+1d"
}).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    var date = ?????;
    alert("Chosen date is: " + date);
});
```

How do i assign selected value to *var date*? I've tried

```
var date = $('#dt_due').datepicker('getDate');
```

But date is null then.

Comment: var date = $('#dt_due').val();

Comment: @FranciscoFernandez I've tried that too, but then it doesn't display at all. All i get is *Chosen date is: *. Not even null.

Comment: Its because the value must be in Date type, try with something like this:
$('input[type="date"]').change(function () {
        alert(this.value);         alert(new Date(this.value));
        var inputDate = new Date(this.value);
    });

Comment: Here you have a demo https://jsfiddle.net/rc9wu3o7/

Comment: @FranciscoFernandez Thank you very much! It turns out that event.format() does the trick too.